# QGIS - How do I embed my layer's database connections into the project (rather than DB Manager)?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, connection, qgs, dbmanager

**Situation:**

I have projects, lots of projects. They call dozens of layers from the corporate PostGIS.
This is largely public data, and the data is referenced via a readonly user account.
As it happens, the layers in these projects are referenced in the project with the username and password.

This is deeply convenient, as it means the projects can be used by any corporate user without permissions requests the vast majority of these users won't understand.

**Problem:**

However, if I add further layers to these projects (which I am doing constantly), then the  in the project file does not include the User= and Password=, rather, the permissions are granted via the connection granted from the DB Manager...
...which does not seem to save (and I don't control for corporate users), so every time I load an amended project I (and my users) are pestered to fill in the DB connection details for those added layers.
I have had this problem in the past, and then had it go away. Possibly because I have rebuilt these projects from the source QGIS 2.18.18 original (our existing corporate QGIS version). But I don't want to be doing this forever. We are in the process of moving from QGIS2 to QGIS3, so I need a solution to this.

**Detail:**

Systems:

QGIS 3.16.8-4 (though it has happened with previous QGIS3 versions - because I rebuilt project from QGIS 2.18.18 source?)

Postgres 9.3

What a native project layer looks like:
dbname='xxxx' host=xxxx port=5432 *user='xxxx' password='xxxx'* sslmode=disable key='xxx' srid=27700

What a newly-added project layer looks like:
dbname='xxxx' host=xxxx port=5432 sslmode=disable key='xxx' srid=27700

QGIS GUI on native project layer:

Right-click on layer and select "Change Data Source" - I can see *full* credentials above. But not way to interact.
Go to layer properties and select the "Source" tab and bizarrely you don't get any of the database connection data.

QGIS GUI on new project layer:

Right-click on layer and select "Change Data Source" - I can see *limited* credentials above. But not way to interact.
Go to layer properties and select the "Source" tab and bizarrely you don't get any of the database connection data.

**What I have tried:**

a) I have tried to google search for "QGIS How to embed database connections in the project file" - no useful answers.

b) I have tried to explore the GUI options like "Change Data Source" and the Properties "Source" tab  - nothing to interact with.

c) I have tried manually editing the .QGS file so every newly added layer includes in the  string a "user='xxxx' password='xxxx'" just like the native project layers - but this still prompts for credentials when I load the project fresh on a newly opened instance of QGIS. Newly opened, i.e. hasn't retained the credentials from a previous project loading prompt.

**What I want - Simply Put:**

1. To understand how it is that my existing projects (converted from QGIS2 as they are), can happily contain full DB connection credentials for existing layers, and yet this is not happening when I re-save amendments to the project which add new layers.
2. What tools are available to me to embed the full connection credentials for new layers in the project, such that users without a DB Manager connection saved won't be pestered for credentials when they load the project.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether you really ticked the "Store" checkboxes in your PostGIS connection **before** adding your new layers e.g. below screenshot.

By doing so, I'm able to retain password infos in my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With help from @ThomasG77, I think we have this answered:

To clarify the process I questioned above - you do indeed need to store the DB connections and save project [before] adding new layers. Doing it this way does happily result in a fresh run of QGIS/Project loading the project with username/password prompts for new layers.

So, storing the connection in the DB Manager after adding new layers (and then saving the project) is not good enough, it does not then write those credentials into the project against the new layers.

Comment: Not able to reproduce: my user/password are stored in all cases... I create a Connexion with screenshot from my answer. I add table using "Add PostGIS layers" and save the project and get password stored in the project. I open the "DB Manager", choose the previous Connexion, open "Database" > "SQL Windows" and save. Credentials are also saved in the project. Be aware I save the project with `qgs` extension and when I say "the password is stored" I mean I find it by searching it in the qgs file opened in a text editor after saving project (whereas the QGIS GUI does not show it)